# in asp.net =send system info to my server by click on a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i catch(get) systeminfo by asp.net language.
put a button in asp form and write a code in it, 
when user click on it send her system info to my server.
system info(like cpu 2.4 -hdd 500g -ram 2ddr3 -main ASUS Monitor Acer 15 &...).

do that by

source code or run a syntax or a component

thanks

Comment: no,you can't get the client system information in the asp.net.because the asp.net running in you web server,not in the client.

Answer (score 0):

In simple ASP.NET, which gets translated to HTML, JavaScript, and CSS in browser, your access is limited to the JavaScript limits, which I don't think include system info of the client. This means that you have access to cookie information, to File API, and to recent capabilities of HTML5.

From the other hand, browser only sends `User-Agent` HTTP header field to the server, which usually includes the version of the browser, the version and the name of the operating system, and usually whether the system is 32bit or 64bit. An example of a `User-Agent` header is:

```
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.797.0 Safari/535.1
```

However, using ActiveX controls, or RIA frameworks like Flash, or Silverlight, you might get a chance to get access to what you want.

I also found this articles, you should read them:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/How-to-Use-JavaScript-for-Hardware-Knowledge/

Comment: Dear @Azeran, I have no project for this, as it's really simple. But to contact me, simply visit [Thought Results](http://thoughtresults.com/contact).